# Freeing shows double free or corruption

Tags: pointers, free

```
typedef struct row_container
{
   int size;
   char *data;
}row_container;


typedef struct message_bar
{
   char message[80];
   time_t message_time;
}message_bar;

typedef struct brick_win_size
{
   int row;
   int col;
   int current_row;
   int current_column;
   int data_row;
   int row_off;
   int col_off;
   row_container *container;
   char *filename;
   message_bar *msg_bar;
}brick_window;



void container_delete_character(struct brick_win_size *win)
{
    uint8_t insert_flag = 1;
    int row = win->current_row;
    int offset = win->current_column;
    row_container *container = win->container;
    char *data = container[row].data;

    if(offset < container[row].size){
        memmove(&data[offset], &data[offset + 1], container[row].size - 1);
        data = realloc(data, container[row].size - 1);
        container[row].data = data;
        container[row].size--;
    }

    if(insert_flag){
        if((container[row].size == 0) && (row < win->data_row)){

            for(int index = row; index < win->data_row; index++){
                if(index != win->data_row -1){
                    container[index] = container[index+1];
                }else{
                   free(container[index]); //error line...............................
                }
            }

            if(win->data_row != 0){
                win->container = realloc(win->container, sizeof(row_container) * (win->data_row - 1));
                win->data_row --;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here in the above code i just want to delete one element at one point in the function. so i am just reassigning pointers with the other pointer and finally i am freeing the final element which is eventually ending up in build failure ***expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘row_container {aka struct row_container}’***

Moreover if i give the & de reference operator it is ending up in double free or corruption error during execution

Comment: could you add the main as well? something we could execute and see the results?

Comment: Actually its a part of big framework and to say it in a nutshell ill be mallocing intially and then realloc to whatever array size i need